# SQL Joining Tables Gives Wrong Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am executing this query :

```
SELECT S.CompanyName,
     COUNT(Visit.Id) AS visit_number,
     COUNT(Client.Id) AS client_number,
     FROM S
     JOIN Visit ON S.Id = Visit.SnId
     JOIN Client ON S.Id = Client.SId
     WHERE Visit.StartedAt >= '2017.01.01' AND Visit.EndedAt< '2018.07.07' 
     GROUP BY S.CompanyName;
```

And it gives result table like :

```
company_name   visit_number   client_number
compnay_name_1    4               4
company_name_2    75              75
```

.
.
.

And those are wrong numbers. When I execute the queries without joining tables, It gives the right result which is not alike the firs query's results. 
I am pretty sure that I didn't make any mistakes. I read lots of question to justify my query but still I can't find a way out. Where is the mistake?

```
SELECT S.CompanyName, COUNT(Visit.Id) AS visit_number
    FROM S
    JOIN Visit ON S.Id = Visit.SId
    WHERE Visit.StartedAt >= '2017.01.01' AND Visit.EndedAt< '2018.07.07' 
    GROUP BY S.CompanyName;
```

This query gives tables like this:

```
company_name   visit_number   

    compnay_name_1    3              
    company_name_2    54
```

Which is nothing like fist one. I was expecting first query to contain this results in visit_number column.

Comment: Could your provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: How do you say they are wrong number, what you are expecting and what is your actual data. You are joining one more table `Client` here which could filter out some results.

Comment: This looks normal to me, joining an extra table should filter out other results which is what it looks like its doing

Comment: Client table have multiple rows against single id having foreign key with s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are aggregating along two independent dimensions.  One solution is to use `count(distinct)`.  However, that can be very computationally intensive.

The recommended alternative is usually to do aggregation *before* the `join`:

```
SELECT s.CompanyName, v.num_visits, c.num_clients
FROM s LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT v.snid, COUNT(*) as num_visits
      FROM Visit v
      WHERE v.StartedAt >= '2017-01-01' AND v.EndedAt < '2018-07-07'
      GROUP BY v.snid
     ) v
     ON s.Id = v.SnId LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.sid, COUNT(*) as num_clients
      FROM Client c
      GROUP BY c.snid
     ) v
     ON s.Id = c.SId
GROUP BY s.CompanyName;
```

Note that this uses `LEFT JOIN`, so all companies are returned, even if they have no visits or clients.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere you have one to many relation because of a double `join`. I think you should use:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT Visit.Id) AS visit_number,
COUNT(DISTINCT Client.Id) AS client_number,
```

Comment: I am trying this right now. All other queries took 1 to 2 minutes but this one is executing for 20 min. Is that normal? I am kinda new to databases.

Comment: @eVader Well, `DISTINCT` may have bad influence on performance, but this is what you need most probably. You can try defining indexes on columns to speed up query execution. Also, you may want show your sample data and desired result, so we could answer more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

```
JOIN Visit ON S.Id = Visit.SnId
```

Shouldn't this one be:

```
JOIN Visit ON S.Id = Visit.SId
```

Alternatively, replacing the JOIN with LEFT JOIN might help

Comment: Yes, I must be mistaken while copy pasting process but still problem contunies. And I tried left join too.